# Alter Numeric Column to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, one of the column is `DOB` which was currently of Type `Numeric(7,0)`.
Sample values of the column as follows

```
DOB
0
1050418
1050412
1060303
```

I am converting the column in SQL as follows

```
SELECT Convert(Date,Convert(varchar,19000000+DOB),101) as DOB_Date From Test where DOB<>0
```

**My goal is to convert this column to Date Date Type.**

When executing the SQL

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN DOB DATE NULL;
```

Giving error as

> Operand Type Clash:Numeric is incompatible with Date.

Comment: You can't store numeric as date, nor date as numeric. Either you create a new column, update then drop the previous one (and rename if you want) or store your values somewhere else, update to null, alter the type and update the values in the correct format.

Comment: Numbers arent' dates. You may use numbers that *look* like dates if converted to text. In this case though it's hard to guess what `1050418` means. If you want to convert that number to a date you'll have to explain what it means

Comment: `cast(cast(19000000 +DOB as varchar(10)) as date)` will give you a date which you can store in a temporary `date` column. You'll have to drop the old column and rename the new one to replace the old, using [sp_rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-renaming-a-column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two choices, not much difference overall.

1) Alter the column data type to be a textual form (e.g. `varchar(10)`). Then convert the textual values in-place into a form that can unambiguously be converted to a date (e.g. `YYYYMMDD` with no separators) and then perform a second data type conversion.

2) Create a new column of date type. Perform an update using your existing expression to set the new values. The drop the old column and (if necessary) rename the new column to match the old column name.

Comment: Thanks Damien. I want go with 1) and sample code as below   
      ALTER TABLE #Test1
       ALTER COLUMN DOB VARCHAR(10) NULL;

UPDATE #Test1 SET DOB=NULL
WHERE DOB='0'

UPDATE #Test1 SET DOB=cast(19000000+cast(DOB AS INT) as varchar(10))
WHERE DOB is not null

ALTER TABLE #Test1
ALTER COLUMN DOB DATE NULL;

SELECT * FROM #Test1

Answer (score 0):

You can add a computed column to the table to do the transformation:

```
alter table t
    add dob_date as (case when dob > 0 then cast(cast(dob + 19000000 as varchar(10)) as date) end);
```

If you want to do this in place, then you can do in multiple steps:

```
alter table t alter dob varchar(8);

update t
    set dob = (case when dob <> '0' then 19000000 + dob end);

alter table t alter dob date;
```

This does a log of type conversion, but it should work.